# No puedo hacer include a un formulario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Intento incluir un formulario externo a mi pagina con el siguiente código y no lo consigo.

```
<?php include('resources/views/cuentas/clientes/form_natural.php'); ?>
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> ErrorException in e142493e739d809fa1fc8b91d876e4c6d92279b2.php line
>   39: include(resources/views/cuentas/clientes/form_natural.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory (View:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juntaAgua/resources/views/cuentas/clientes/create.blade.php)

Este es el árbol de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intente con el metodo `@include('')` que laravel ofrece y nada.

Formulario que intento incluir **form_natural.php**

```html
<div id="form_natural">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Formulario de registro de un cliente natural</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-lg-8">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" disabled class="form-control" name="razon_social" value="natural"
                               placeholder="Numero de cédula...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cedula">Numero de cédula</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cedula" value="{{old('cedula')}}"
                               placeholder="Numero de cédula...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Nombre..." name="nombre"
                               value="{{old('nombre')}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Dirección..." name="direccion"
                               value="{{old('direccion')}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Teléfono..." name="telefono"
                               value="{{old('telefono')}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Correo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Correo..." name="correo"
                               value="{{old('correo')}}">
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <button type="reset" name="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>&nbsp;Limpiar
            </button>
            <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Guardar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando [app_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-app-path)

```
include(app_path() . '\resouces\views\cuentas\clientes\form_natural.php');
```

**Actualización:**

El problema se soluciono con el uso de `@include`

```
@include('cuentas.clientes.form_natural');
```

Comment: `include(app_path() . '/resources/views/cuentas/clientes/form_natural.php');`  Sigo obteniendo el error :( , añadí al post el formulario que quiero incluir  `ErrorException in e142493e739d809fa1fc8b91d876e4c6d92279b2.php line 42:
include(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juntaAgua/app/resources/views/cuentas/clientes/form_natural.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juntaAgua/resources/views/cuentas/clientes/create.blade.php)`

Comment: Tomando en cuenta que lo que quieres incluir es una vista porque no le cambias el nombre así `form_natural.blade.php` y luego lo incluyes con `@include('')` aquì dejo un [recipe](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template)

También puedes hacerlo así `@include('directorio.fichero');` que en tu caso quedaría `@include('cuentas.clientes.form_natural');` no se me ocurre mas nada.

Comment: amigo funciono con `@include('cuentas.clientes.form_natural')`, pero no entiendo por que no funciona  con php <?php include ('cuentas/clientes/form_natural''); ?>

Comment: Porque no es la forma de hacer eso en Laravel? nunca intente incluir una vista de esa forma en Laravel, pero si miras la sección [Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) veras que en ningún lado usan `<?php include...?>`

Comment: listo amigo muchas gracias puede colocar como respuesta para aceptarla muchas gracias :)

Comment: de nada, acabo de actualizar la respuesta para poner la solución.

Answer (score 0):

se supone que la tienes en la misma carpeta entonces no tienes porque hacer toda esa extencion solo hacer esto....bueno asi lo hago yo

```
<?php include 'form_natural.php'; ?>
```

o

```
<?php include "form_natural.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, aun sigo teniendo el error  no es necesario que tenga la extensión `.blade.php` para poder incluirlo?? añadí al post el formulario que deseo incluir